# CoffeeScript Reference error

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

So I keep getting the following error with my code:

```
Reference Error: ws is not defined
```

My code is this:

```
config = require "./config.json"
chalk = require "chalk"
shortid = require "shortid"
maxplayers = config.maxplayers

WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server
wss = new WebSocketServer({port: config.port})

wss.on "connection", (ws) ->
    console.log "Socket " + chalk.green("connected") + "."

    ws.on "message", (msg) ->
        console.log "Received packet: " + msg

    return

console.log "Server " + chalk.cyan("started") + " on port " + config.port + "."
```

Why is this happening? CoffeeScript's Try page gives me exactly what I want. Why does NPM CoffeeScript not do it? If I do `coffee -c myscriptname` (yes I replaced myscriptname with my script name), it gives me this:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.9.1
(function() {
  ws.on("message", function(msg) {
    return console.log("Received packet: " + msg);
  });

  return;

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, although I don't know the module you're using. I'm guessing that `on` handler is getting called a different way than you expect. Have you tried stepping through in a debugger?

Comment: How would I do that? Also the module is [this](http://einaros.github.io/ws/)

Comment: What version of coffeescript are you running? `coffee -c file.coffee` with your code gives me [this](https://gist.github.com/sethkrasnianski/db5871d374a47a11ace2)

Comment: Doesn't look like it

Comment: Yes, it returns the same thing.